# SQL SUMed up data with clause

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I have 2 tables:

users

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  0 |
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

payments

```
+---------+--------+------+
| user_id | amount | case |
+---------+--------+------+
|     0   |   10   |   1  |
|     0   |    1   |   2  |
|     2   |    5   |   1  |
|     2   |    4   |   1  |
|     2   |    5   |   2  |
|     3   |   26   |   2  |
+---------+--------+------+
```

And I'm trying to get output:

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user_id | total_amount_case_1 | total_amount_case_2 |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|     0   |                10   |                  1  |
|     2   |                 9   |                  5  |
|     3   |                 0   |                 26  |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Explaining in words I'm trying to select each user who has at least one payment and SUM its payments.amount in separated cases.

I just could get to the point where I select each user total payments, but without depending on what case it was:

```
SELECT users.id AS user_id, SUM(payments.amount) AS total_amount FROM users LEFT JOIN users.id = payments.user_id GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY user_id;
```

Which gave me this output:

```
+---------+--------------+
| user_id | total_amount |
+---------+--------------+
|     0   |         11   |
|     1   |          0   |
|     2   |         14   |
|     3   |         26   |
+---------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  u.id AS user_id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.`case` = 1 THEN p.amount ELSE 0 END) AS total_amount_case_1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.`case` = 2 THEN p.amount ELSE 0 END) AS total_amount_case_2 
FROM
  users u
  LEFT JOIN payments p ON u.id = p.user_id 
GROUP BY u.user_id 
ORDER BY u.user_id ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with conditional aggregation -- using the `case` statement in an aggregation function:

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id,
       SUM(case when p.`case` = 1 then p.amount else 0 end) AS total_amount_case1,
       SUM(case when p.`case` = 2 then p.amount else 0 end) AS total_amount_case2
FROM users u LEFT JOIN 
     payments p
     on u.id = p.user_id
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id;
```

I also added table aliases to make the query a bit less cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.id AS user_id, 
   SUM(case when Payments.Case = 1 then payments.amount else 0 End) AS total_amount_case1, 
   SUM(case when Payments.Case = 2 then payments.amount else 0 End) AS total_amount_case2  
FROM users LEFT JOIN payments on
   users.id = payments.user_id 
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY users.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.id As user_id
     , Sum(CASE WHEN payments.case = 1 THEN payments.amount ELSE 0 END) As total_amount_case_1
     , Sum(CASE WHEN payments.case = 2 THEN payments.amount ELSE 0 END) As total_amount_case_2
FROM   users
 LEFT
  JOIN payments
    ON users.id = payments.user_id
GROUP
    BY user_id
ORDER
    BY user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something on the lines of the following:

```
SELECT users.id
,SUM(CASE WHEN payments.[case] = 1 THEN total_amount_case_1 ELSE 0 END) as total_amount_case_1
,SUM(CASE WHEN payments.[case] = 2 THEN total_amount_case_2 ELSE 0 END) as total_amount_case_2
FROM users INNER JOIN payments
ON users.id = payments.user_id
GROUP BY payments.user_id
```